# jQuery Mobile Form Validation - Which Plugin to choose?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, forms, jquery-mobile

Which framework would you choose to validate forms in a jQuery Mobile app? 
In addition my webapp runs in the PhoneGap native wrapper on iPhone and Android.

There are numerous jQuery form validation frameworks out there - but from your experience what works well with the mobile version of jQuery?

Criteria that would be interesting in the mobile context:

- touch-enabled notification messages - in case of wrong validation the message is ideally optimized for small screen estate
- message in place with the wrong form field
- offline functionality - since the PhoneGap app runs occasionally without network access

Answer (score 1):

try this one:
http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/
it worked pretty neatly for me,

Comment: I'm very interested if anyone has any insight to add here - mostly, how well it plays with jQMobile (styles, ui, etc).

Comment: At the moment it causes conflicts which cause some jQM elements to break. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067275/jquery-validation-jquery-mobile-conflict

Answer (score 0):

I'll second the vote for the validation plugin.  It shouldn't have any conflict with jqMobile since it simply works on the submit() action.  Basically it intercepts the submit and applies a series of rules to check the form. You can have custom rules, custom error locations, etc.  About the only thing I've had trouble with is using it with a class of fields.  It pretty much wants individual names/IDs to validate.

Comment: Again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067275/jquery-validation-jquery-mobile-conflict

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently trying to use that plugin with JQM 1.2 and it breaks form submission handling. when i enable the plugin and submit a form successfully, the browser takes me to the action.php file that was specified in the form. when i disable the plugin, the form submits and the returned html is displayed properly via ajax and the .php file is properly never shown. so i don't think this plugin is great for JQM...