# jQuery Validation & jQuery Mobile Conflict

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-validate

I'm currently using jQuery Mobile and [this validation framework](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/).

Everything was fine until I tried to create a jQM multiselect select menu. The elements render but it make the options unselectable.

Has anyone else encountered this and found a solution?

Comment: Are you pulling the latest from Github? https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly, the packed version of the jQuery Validate isn't compatible with jQM.

The unpacked and minified versions seem to work fine, however.